# How to get aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc?

Tags: python, linux, gnu, arm64, raspberry-pi4

Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75797418/unable-to-install-pythons-pyrfc-library-for-sap-on-raspberry-pi-4) question for context

As stated in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75797418/unable-to-install-pythons-pyrfc-library-for-sap-on-raspberry-pi-4) question. I will require **aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc** to be able to install the pyrfc library.
How to setup **aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc**?

Tried *sudo apt install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu* but still the same issue

I am using raspbian OS on raspberry pi 4B with python 3.9.
What changes do I need to make to make this work?

Comment: arch64-linux-gnu-gcc is not available in your repositories for arm64 architecture devices.

Comment: Is there any work around for that or i can't use that specific library on raspberry pi?

Comment: I searched apt for a workaround with `apt search linux-gnu`, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the source code for the gcc compiler from the official website. You can download the latest version from here: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-11.2.0/gcc-11.2.0.tar.xz

wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-11.2.0/gcc-11.2.0.tar.xz

2. Extract the source code:

   tar xf gcc-11.2.0.tar.xz
3. Change to the directory where the source code was extracted:

   cd gcc-11.2.0
4. Configure the build:

   ./configure --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local
5. Build and install the compiler:

   make -j4 && sudo make install
   This will build and install the aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc compiler into the /usr/local/bin directory.
6. Verify that aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc is installed:

   aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc --version
   This should display the version of aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc that is installed on your system.

Comment: It is already installed as I can already see the version of it